# Why the model is null in Action method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my problem is that after click on button "Save", I get the model passed to controller from view is null.

Here my code of the View and Controller.
Do you know where I am doing wrong?
Thank you so much.

**View** Certificazioni.cshtml

```
@model List<ElencoCertificazioniItem>
...

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
...
        <tbody>
        @{
             for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
             {
                  <tr>
                     <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].Id) </td>
                     <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].description)</td>
                     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Field1.Value)</td>
                     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Field2.Value)</td>
                   </tr>
              }
           }
          </tbody>
         }
 ....
```

}

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpParamAction]
    public ActionResult SaveItems(List<ElencoCertificazioniItem> model)
    {
        //the items here is null!!! ;(
        return saveItems(model);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class ElencoCertificazioniItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool? Field1 { get; set; }
    public bool? Field2 { get; set; }

}
```

I use HttpParamAction to manage calls to different methods controller (I have 2 button in the same form).

```
public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

The list is not null and contains right count elements, but the items within are null and Id properties is always 0!

Comment: Show your model. And do your mean `model` is `null`, or its an empty collection, of that some properties of the items in the collection are `null`? (you do not generate any form controls for properties `id` and `description`). And what is the `[HttpParamAction]` attribute?

Comment: Do you have more than one submit button (because you use `[HttpParamAction]`)? Maybe your collection is posted to the wrong action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID and description will always be 0 and null because you don't use any input to post them in form. If you want return them, you have to use input hiddent to pass this values

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].description)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].description)
    </td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Field1)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Field2)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ok thank you...I Confirm Now Id and description are valued...very thanks

Comment: the answer is also that of Stephen Muecke ...
 
"And since Field1 is a nullable bool, it needs to be @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Field1) (no Value at the end) – Stephen Muecke"

Thank you so much guys